# How to make a SWT java program working with both 32 and 64 JVM?

Tags: java, jvm, swt, 32bit-64bit

I'm using SWT and i want to make one program that works with 32 and 64 JVM.
My solution is stupid and i don't think it will work but if i simply add both SWT (32 and 64 bit) JARs to my build path, does it work?
It's a bit vague because they both contain the same packages, and when i import a package, how can i know from which JAR i imported it?
And if i can specify from which JAR i'm importing, is it possible to do it by using *System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model"))* ?
I'm searching java code solutions because i found some solutions with - as i think - xml files but i didn't understand them and i prefer resolving this problem using java.
Otherwise, please explain to me any method that does the work.

Comment: Sorry, but you have to create two separate JAR files.  One for x86 and one for x64.

Comment: Did yo googled about this topic?Search in stack-overflow itself there are many related posts.

Comment: I searched, but as i said, i found solutions using other type of files (i think it's XML) but i didn't understand how to add these files. I also thought hopefully there are other solutions using only java code. And my english is not that good so maybe i didn't type the most precise keywords.